# Javascript Destructuring an array

Tags: javascript, destructuring

I am trying to learn how destructuring works and encountered a challenge. I destructured results into a data variable and I was wondering how I would further destructure itemsInCart and buyerCountry.

```
function makeArray() {
  return {
    results: [
      {
        itemsInCart: [
          {
            name: "pizza",
            price: 74,
            qty: 1
          },
          {
            name: "Pepper Soup",
            price: 32,
            qty: 2
          }
        ],
        buyerCountry: "Rwanda"
      }
    ]
  };
}

const {
  results: [data]
} = makeArray();

console.log(data);
```

below is my output so far:

```
{
    itemsInCart: [{
            name: 'pizza',
            price: 74,
            qty: 1
        },
        {
            name: 'Pepper Soup',
            price: 32,
            qty: 2
        }
    ],
    buyerCountry: 'Rwanda'
} => undefined
```

Comment: Hi Martin, what is the desired output? [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) provides a great guide.

Comment: `const {results: [{buyerCountry, itemsInCart}]} = makeArray()`. `console.log(buyerCountry, itemsInCart);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to further destructure the `data` object that you've obtained by doing the following:

```
/* Your current destructuring */
const { results: [data] } = makeArray();

/* Additional destructuring step to get itemsInCard and buyerCountry */
const { itemsInCart, buyerCountry } = data;

console.log(itemsInCart, buyerCountry);
```

This can also be reduced into a single line by the following:

```js
function makeArray() {
  return {
    results: [{
      itemsInCart: [{
          name: "pizza",
          price: 74,
          qty: 1
        },
        {
          name: "Pepper Soup",
          price: 32,
          qty: 2
        }
      ],
      buyerCountry: "Rwanda"

    }]
  }
};


const { results: [{ itemsInCart, buyerCountry }] } = makeArray();

console.log('itemsInCart:', itemsInCart);
console.log('buyerCountry:', buyerCountry);
```